# Bad parameters to execve

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

I want execute with `excve()` the next: `/bin/sh` ABC.
The three args are a char array (1 char = 1 byte), but the `strace` utility says I'm trying execute:

```
execve("//bin/sh", ["//bin/sh", "ABC", 0x6e69622f, 0x68732f, ...], [/* 0 vars */]) = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
```

Function:

```
int execve(const char* filename, char* const argv[], char* const envp[])
```

And this is my code:

```
push 0x00434241  ; "ABC\0"
mov esi, esp     ; &"ABC\0"
push 0x0068732f  ; "/sh\0"
push 0x6e69622f  ; "/bin"
mov ebx, esp     ; &"//bin/sh\0"
push esi         ; &"ABC\0"
push ebx         ; &"//bin/sh\0"
mov ecx, esp     ; args["//bin/sh\0", "ABC\0"]
push 0           ; NULL ; NULL NULL NULL NULL
mov edx, esp     ; envp[NULL]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `argv` array needs to be zero terminated. Add a `push 0` before the `push esi`.

Comment: Ok! But why is needed 4 NULLs if the array is of chars (1 char = 1 byte)?

Comment: Because what you are terminating is the array, which is made up of 4 byte pointers. Not the string, which is made up of 1 byte chars, and must also be terminated (you do that correctly).